# How to display powershell output to TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that downloads a file from a website.

I'd like to show the progress of the download in an TextBox of my form.

How can I do that?

**EDIT:**

I start my process with:

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe", "-executionpolicy remotesigned -file C:\temp\test.ps1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the [Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows you to run the script and re-direct the standards streams.

Comment: Thx for ur quick answer :) Finally, how exactly to do that?

Comment: @hannir  Go to the link in the answer and investigate all the different things that, that class, will do.

Comment: You mean something like [that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) right?

Comment: That will be to send input to the process.  To get data back you need to redirect the standardoutput